# Force project build regardless of existing changes in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build

I have the following project structure (only relevant parts are included):

**Resources**: contains classes that read localization information from the database and can generate code for strongly-typed resources

**ResourceBuilder**: uses a database configuration to generate a strongly typed resource file (`bin\debug\Resources.cs`) that looks like the following:

```
public class Resources {
    private static IResourceProvider resourceProvider;

    public static void SetProvider(IResourceProvider provider)
    {
        resourceProvider = provider;
    }

public static string HomeCategory => (string) resourceProvider.GetResource("HomeCategory", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

public static string HomeAllCategories => (string) resourceProvider.GetResource("HomeAllCategories", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

    // ...
}
```

This project has the following settings:

- Run the post-build event: Always
- Post-build event command line: "$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\ResourceBuilder.exe"

So, if this project builds, it will automatically run itself and generate the resources file.

Other projects are directly referencing static properties from `Resources` class.

Development cycle for resource changes (add/remove) is the following:

- change database entry
- manually run `ResourceBuilder`
- build the solution

Manually running of `ResourceBuilder` is required because Visual Studio skips its building, if there are no code changes (only database changes

**Question: is it possible to configure ResourceBuilder project to always be built regardless of changes?**